# Vim press ENTER to continue

Tags: linux, editing, shell, vim

When using vim to run a shell command, eg. with

```
:!ls
```

or

```
:sh
```

to get into a shell, I always have the prompt

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This is fine for "internal" vim commands like `:ls`, for which the screen must pause to allow me to see the output, but when I want to run script eg. `:!./%` then I have to press enter after running it. Is there an option that will allow vim commands to pause but not shell commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
:silent !ls
```

Comment: Note that you'll only see the output of any commands you run with :silent when you EXIT vim.

Comment: He didn't say anything about that -> he just doesn't want to press enter.

Comment: :silent is documented in the help as the way to prevent the "Press ENTER" message. There should be a 'shortmess' flag for this, but none exists.